# Destination in autofill where range has two variables - Range Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a selection autofill macro for two variables that are stored ranges.

The error is

> 1004: Range of object_Global fail

on the line

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(bobjGLOrigCell, bobjGLLast), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

```vb
Sub Automation_BOBJ()

Dim startPointBobjGL As Range
Dim bobjGLNextCell As Range
Dim bobjGLLastCell As Range

Set startPointBobjGL = Range("A3")
Set bobjGLNextCell = startPointBobjGL.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
Set bobjGLLastCell = startPointBobjGL.End(xlToRight).Offset(13, 1)

bobjGLNextCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],R2C2:R27C15,(MONTH(TODAY())+1),0)"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(startPointBobjGL, bobjGLLast), Type:=xlFillDefault

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "103100335.7"

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? Note, that the line `bobjGLNextCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4]...` can generate an error if `bobjGLNextCell` is still `A3`, `B3`, `C3` or `D3` because the lookup value must be 4 columns to the left. The other line which can cause a problem is `Selection.AutoFill....` if nothing is selected or no particular sheet is activated first. You might want to be more precise here. Try one of these examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx

Comment: I am getting the error on this line: Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(bobjGLOrigCell, bobjGLLast), Type:=xlFillDefault

The error is 1004: Range of object_Global failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be like this...

```
bobjGLNextCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(bobjGLNextCell, bobjGLLastCell), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: I am getting the error autofill method of range class failed with this

Comment: Okay lets take an example. Suppose your formula is in A2 and you want to fill that formula in the range A3:A15, a syntax would be like Range("A2").AutoFill Range("A2:A15"), xlFillDefault. Here note that the formula cell is also included in the destination range A2:A15.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this:

```
Set startPointBobjGL = Sheets("Sheet").Range("A3")
```